# Jest coverage for testing useEffect that updates the style of an element

Tags: java, css, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am a beginner to Jest and React and writing code for a scroll button component in React with a useEffect function as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
            square && (square.style.transform = `translateX(-${scroll}px)`);
        });
```

where `scroll` is a component state that is updated whenever I click on a button.

I am not sure how to get coverage with my code in Jest, but here's what I've done so far:

```
 it('test transformX', () => {
    const squareMock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        style: { transform: jest.fn() } 
    });
    const {getByLabelText} = render(
        <ScrollButton square={ squareMock } />
    );
    const rightButton = getByLabelText('rightButton');
    fireEvent.click(rightButton);
    });
```

How do I proceed from here? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you shouldn't modify DOM directly in a `useEffect`, you should let React render to the DOM for you. E.g. your code should look more like,

```
const ScrollButton() {
  const [scroll] = useState(0);
  const [transform, setTransform] = useState(undefined);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTransform(`translateX(-${scroll}px)`);
  }, [scroll]);

  return (
    <div style={{ transform }}>my square</div>
  )
}
```

However if you're asking specifically about testing `useEffect()` you can `await` [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) a style change (or other DOM change),

```
// inside test
// render component
// next wait for useEffect to run
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(queryByText('my square'))
    .toHaveStyle({transform: `translateX(-10px)`});
});
// rest of test follows
```

If your useEffect has dependencies then testing those involves changing those dependencies by interacting like a user would. Ie, your test would simulate clicking a button whose onClick handler sets a setState `scroll` and triggers a `useEffect(fn, [ scroll ])` side effect. Test effects by acting like a user.

Don't mock `useEffect()` or test useEffect directly. Also don't expect to find a `runAllTimers()` equivalent like `runAllEffects()` or similar, that's not the right way to think about testing effects.

Do test effects by testing their expected side effects when their dependencies change.